# dist folder not generated when building typescript in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, microservices

I'm working a a nodejs microservices project, and trying to build the services in a docker container. The problem is that I could not see the dist folder generated. But when I run npm start or npm run build locally, each of the services get built and the dist folder is generated. I would like to build with `docker build -t container-name .` and `docker-compose` so that my changes can be compiled in real time. I have attached my scripts from package.json and Dockerfile for review on one of the services. Thank you.

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build && node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=dev ts-node-dev --poll src/index.ts",
    "build": "rimraf ./dist && rimraf tsconfig.tsbuildinfo && tsc",
    "start_mongo": "brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community",
    "stop_mongo": "brew services stop mongodb/brew/mongodb-community",
    "start_rabbit": "brew services start rabbitmq",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:20-alpine as development

WORKDIR /app/user_service

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:20-alpine as production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /app/user_service

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm ci --only=production

COPY --from=development /app/user_service/dist ./dist

EXPOSE 8001

CMD ["node", "dist/index.js"]
```

I have tried to rebuild the containers several time but same, it would only compile when I run the build command locally, and does not get updated with changes.

Comment: Why use multiple `FROM` of the same image?

Comment: Docker isn't a good tool for a live-development environment, since its core model is around immutable images that are isolated from the host filesystem.  In your case your final image has only the built production application and not the original source.  Can you use Node without Docker for this use case?

Comment: @Kevin Kopf, It's a multi-stage build

Answer (score 1):

Your `COPY` command is missing a final `/` both for the destination and the source paths

```
COPY --from=development /app/user_service/dist/ ./dist/
```

Given that both are folders and not files, they must end with `/`, as described in [Docker's documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy):

> `COPY <src> <dest>`
>
> - If `<src>` is any other kind of file, it is copied individually along
>   with its metadata. In this case, if `<dest>` ends with a trailing
>   slash `/`, it will be considered a directory and the contents of
>   `<src>` will be written at `<dest>/base(<src>)`.
> - If multiple `<src>` resources are specified, either directly or due to the use of a wildcard, then `<dest>` must be a directory, and it must end with a slash `/`.
> - If `<dest>` does not end with a trailing slash, it will be considered a
>   regular file and the contents of `<src>` will be written at `<dest>`.
> - If `<dest>` doesn't exist, it is created along with all missing
>   directories in its path.

Comment: Thanks @Hugo Sangaletti. I have updated that now, but still did not solve my problem. The dist folder is still not seen being generated. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

COPY Command must be

> COPY --from=development /app/user_service/dist/ ./dist/

and then you must run the docker as development to create dist/ files
then run it as production